# Android - class is not a view android.support.v4.fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I have to use fragment, with v4 support, but I've got an error crashing the App.
I can't find the solution!

This is my code :

**activity_advert_list.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    android:id="@+id/advertListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.myapp.fragment.AdvertListFragment"/>
```

**AdvertListActivity.java**

```
package com.myapp.app;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.myapp.R;
import com.myapp.classmodel.Advert;
import com.myapp.fragment.AdvertDetailFragment;
import com.myapp.interf.OnAdvertSelectedListener;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class AdvertListActivity extends FragmentActivity implements     OnAdvertSelectedListener {
private AdvertListActivity activity = this;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_advert_list);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Google Analytics
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Google Analytics
    EasyTracker.getInstance().activityStop(this);
}


/**
 * Called by fragment
 * Used to pass advertList & current position to detail fragment
 */
@Override
public void onAdvertItemSelected(ArrayList<Advert> advertList, int currentPosition) {
    AdvertDetailFragment fragment = (AdvertDetailFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.advertDetailFragment);
    if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {
        fragment.setData(advertList, currentPosition);
    } 
}

}
```

**EDIT**

**Logcat with android.support.v4.app.Fragment :**

```
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.app.AdvertListActivity}:    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.Fragment
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.Fragment
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:604)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at com.myapp.app.AdvertListActivity.onCreate(AdvertListActivity.java:19)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    ... 11 more
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v4.app.Fragment cannot be cast to android.view.View
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:1380)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
04-22 11:09:48.223: E/AndroidRuntime(30349):    ... 22 more
```

**Logcat with fragment**

```
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.app.AdvertListActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:  Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at  com.myapp.app.AdvertListActivity.onCreate(AdvertListActivity.java:19)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at  android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    ... 11 more
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at com.myapp.fragment.AdvertListFragment.onCreateView(AdvertListFragment.java:63)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:846)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1061)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1160)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:272)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
04-22 11:07:39.950: E/AndroidRuntime(30107):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: what your logCat says?

Comment: <android.support.v4.app.Fragment use this <fragment

Comment: now you have error in AdvertListFragment.java line number 63

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use this way its work

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/firstf"
    android:name="com.example.fragments_slider.fregment_classOne"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: This won't work on pre-ICS devices though, right? That's not using the support library.

Answer (score 13):

For both native fragments (`android.app.Fragment`) and support fragments (`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`), syntax in XML layout file is identical.

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.myfragment"
    ... />
```

But when you use support fragments in an activity, your activity must inherits `FragmentActivity`(from support package) not native `Activity`. On the other hand, when you're using native fragments, your activity   could extends `Activity`. But it's recommended that always use support fragments instead of native fragments even if your target device has Android 4 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

just in case someone make the same mistake as i do.
If you forget to add

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

in FragmentActivity's onCreate method. you'll receive the mistake.