# Class is not a view android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am struggling to add this Fragment in to my XML layout.

In my Activity XML layout i have the following:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_invitefriendsprogress"
                android:name="tv.superawesome.club.android.ui.fragments.InviteFriendsProgressFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:layout="@layout/fragment_invitefriendsprogress" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

I get a strange error:

```
XML file line #205: Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

line 205 is:

```
<fragment
```

Am I missing something?

For reference here is the full XML layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/small" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/starpink" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/man"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/star"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/star"
        android:src="@drawable/invitepink" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/inwrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/inTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="18dp"
                    android:text="@string/intitle"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/indescriptiob"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:text="@string/indescription"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/emailedittext"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="@string/yoemail"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="12sp" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addbutton"
                    style="@style/OButton"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/addinvite"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/mailsdescriptiom"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/emailsofar"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/emailsscrollview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="92dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/emailslayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@color/light_gray"
                        android:orientation="vertical" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/emailrow"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                            <com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.CustomTextView
                                android:id="@+id/emailaddresstextview"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_weight="0.9"
                                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                                android:text="PlaceHolder"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/cancelimageview"
                                android:layout_width="15dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                                android:src="@drawable/abs_clear" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </ScrollView>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/sendbutton"
                    style="@style/OButton"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/mfriends"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/friendindicator"
                    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/inviteprogressbutton"
                style="@style/OrangeSmallButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:text="abc"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_myfragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.fragments.MyFragment"
                 />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<include layout="@layout/layout_toast" />
```

Here is also the Fragment Class:

```
public class MyFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    private CustomTextView mTitle;
    private CustomTextView mDescription;
    private CustomTextView mStar5Description;
    private CustomTextView mStar10Description;
    private ImageView mStar1, mStar2, mStar3, mStar4, mStar5, mStar6, mStar7,
            mStar8, mStar9, mStar10;
    private Button mFriends5Button;
    private Button mFriends10Button;
    private Button mInviteFriendsButton;
    private int inviteCount;
    private View mRootView = null;

    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private void setAlphaForView(View v, float alpha) {
        AlphaAnimation animation = new AlphaAnimation(alpha, alpha);
        animation.setDuration(0);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        v.startAnimation(animation);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        if (mRootView != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) mRootView.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(mRootView);
        }
        try {
            mRootView = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.fragment_invitefriendsprogress, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
            /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
        }



        mTitle = (CustomTextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.progressTitle);
        mDescription = (CustomTextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.progressDescription);
        mStar5Description = (CustomTextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.progress5starDescription);
        mStar10Description = (CustomTextView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.progress10StarDescription);
        mStar1 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar1);
        mStar2 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar2);
        mStar3 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar3);
        mStar4 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar4);
        mStar5 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar5);
        mStar6 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar6);
        mStar7 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar7);
        mStar8 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar8);
        mStar9 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar9);
        mStar10 = (ImageView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitestar10);
        mFriends5Button = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.guarantee5button);
        mFriends10Button = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.guarantee10button);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.invitesProgressBar);



        inviteCount = BoxStatusCache.getInstance(mRootView.getContext().getApplicationContext()).inviteCount;

        if (MyTheme.getTheme(mRootView.getContext()) == MyTheme.BOA) {

            mRootView.findViewById(R.id.bglayout).setBackgroundResource(
                    R.drawable.bgawesome);
            mTitle.setCustom(false);
            mTitle.setCustom(true, CustomTextView.BOATITLEFONT);
            mTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple));
            mDescription.setCustom(true, CustomTextView.BOADESCFONT);
            mStar5Description.setCustom(true, CustomTextView.BOADESCFONT);
            mStar10Description.setCustom(true, CustomTextView.BOADESCFONT);
            mFriends5Button.setTypeface(CustomTypeface.getTypefaceBOADesc(mRootView.getContext().getApplicationContext()));
            mFriends10Button.setTypeface(CustomTypeface.getTypefaceBOADesc(mRootView.getContext().getApplicationContext()));

        } else {

            mRootView.findViewById(R.id.bglayout).setBackgroundResource(
                    R.drawable.bg);
            mTitle.setCustom(true);

            mFriends5Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pinksmallbutton);
            mFriends10Button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pinksmallbutton);
            mTitle.setCustom(true, CustomTextView.TITLEFONT);
            mTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.pink));
            mDescription.setCustom(true, CustomTextView.DESCFONT);
            mStar5Description.setCustom(true, CustomTextView.DESCFONT);
            mStar10Description.setCustom(true, CustomTextView.DESCFONT);
            mFriends5Button.setTypeface(CustomTypeface.getTypefaceDesc(mRootView.getContext().getApplicationContext()));
            mFriends10Button.setTypeface(CustomTypeface.getTypefaceDesc(mRootView.getContext().getApplicationContext()));


        }

        mStar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);
        mStar2.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);
        mStar3.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);
        mStar4.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);
        mStar5.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);
        mStar6.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);
        mStar7.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);
        mStar8.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);
        mStar9.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);
        mStar10.setImageResource(R.drawable.notinvited);



        // Uncomment this after finish debugging
        if (inviteCount < 10) {
            setAlphaForView(mFriends10Button, 0.5f);
            mFriends10Button.setClickable(false);
            if (inviteCount < 5) {
                setAlphaForView(mFriends5Button, 0.5f);
                mFriends5Button.setClickable(false);
            }
        }

        final Context context = mRootView.getContext();

        mFriends5Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setAlphaForView(mFriends5Button, 0.5f);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        try {
                            HashMap<Object, Object> data = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
                            if (MyTheme.getTheme(context) == MyTheme.TWO) {
                                data.put("site", 1);
                            } else {
                                data.put("site", 0);
                            }

                            data.put("invite_amount", 5);
                            LogUtils.log("redeem data: " + data.toString());

                            String response = HttpRequestController
                                    .getInstance().doRequest(
                                            ApiUrls.REDEEM_INVITATION, data,
                                            Method.POST, MainActivity.token);
                            return new JSONObject(response);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            setAlphaForView(mFriends5Button, 1.0f);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        setAlphaForView(mFriends5Button, 1.0f);
                        try {
                            if (result.getBoolean("success")) {
                                makeGoodToastAndEatIt();
                                LogUtils.log("result MyActivity: "
                                        + result.toString());
                                getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_OK);
                                SyncUtils.forceUpdateProfile();
                            } else {
                                LogUtils.log("error_msg: " + result.toString());
                                if (result.getString("error_msg").contains(
                                        "Not enough")) {
                                    ToastAnimationUtils
                                            .setUpAnimations(
                                                    getActivity(),
                                                    "Not enough invitations. Invite some more friends and try again!",
                                                    false);
                                } else {
                                    ToastAnimationUtils
                                            .setUpAnimations(
                                                    getActivity(),
                                                    "Try again later.",
                                                    false);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            ToastAnimationUtils
                                    .setUpAnimations(
                                            getActivity(),
                                            "Try again later. ",
                                            false);
                        }

                    }
                }.execute();
            }

        });

        mFriends10Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setAlphaForView(mFriends10Button, 0.5f);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        try {
                            HashMap<Object, Object> data = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
                            if (MyTheme.getTheme(context) == MyTheme.BOA) {
                                data.put("site", 1);
                            } else {
                                data.put("site", 0);
                            }

                            data.put("invite_amount", 10);
                            LogUtils.log("redeem data: " + data.toString());

                            String response = HttpRequestController
                                    .getInstance().doRequest(
                                            ApiUrls.REDEEM_INVITATION, data,
                                            Method.POST, MainActivity.token);
                            return new JSONObject(response);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            setAlphaForView(mFriends10Button, 1.0f);
                            return null;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
                        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        setAlphaForView(mFriends10Button, 1.0f);
                        try {
                            if (result.getBoolean("success")) {
                                makeMegaGoodToastAndEatIt();
                                LogUtils.log("result MyActivity: "
                                        + result.toString());
                                getActivity().setResult(MainActivity.RESULT_OK);
                                SyncUtils.forceUpdateProfile();
                            } else {
                                if (result.getString("error_msg").contains(
                                        "Not enough")) {
                                    ToastAnimationUtils
                                            .setUpAnimations(
                                                    getActivity(),
                                                    "Not enough invitations. Invite some more friends and try again!",
                                                    false);
                                } else {
                                    ToastAnimationUtils
                                            .setUpAnimations(
                                                    getActivity(),
                                                    " Try again later.",
                                                    false);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            ToastAnimationUtils
                                    .setUpAnimations(
                                            getActivity(),
                                            "Try again later. ",
                                            false);
                        }

                    }
                }.execute();
            }

        });

        LogUtils.log("inviteCount: " + inviteCount);
        if (inviteCount > 0 && MyTheme.getTheme(getActivity()) == MyTheme.TWO) {
            mStar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
            if (inviteCount > 1) {
                mStar2.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                if (inviteCount > 2) {
                    mStar3.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                    if (inviteCount > 3) {
                        mStar4.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                        if (inviteCount > 4) {
                            mStar5.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                            if (inviteCount > 5) {
                                mStar6.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                if (inviteCount > 6) {
                                    mStar7.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                    if (inviteCount > 7) {
                                        mStar8.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                        if (inviteCount > 8) {
                                            mStar9.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                            if (inviteCount > 9) {
                                                mStar10.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (inviteCount > 0
                && MyTheme.getTheme(getActivity()) == MyTheme.ONE) {
            mStar1.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
            if (inviteCount > 1) {
                mStar2.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                if (inviteCount > 2) {
                    mStar3.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                    if (inviteCount > 3) {
                        mStar4.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                        if (inviteCount > 4) {
                            mStar5.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                            if (inviteCount > 5) {
                                mStar6.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                if (inviteCount > 6) {
                                    mStar7.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                    if (inviteCount > 7) {
                                        mStar8.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                        if (inviteCount > 8) {
                                            mStar9.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                            if (inviteCount > 9) {
                                                mStar10.setImageResource(R.drawable.invited);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return mRootView;

    }

}
```

full logcat:

```
01-03 13:36:18.840: E/ACRA(6144): ACRA caught a RuntimeException exception for com.myapp.jimbob.android. Building report.
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.jimbob.android/com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.activities.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #205: Error inflating class fragment
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #205: Error inflating class fragment
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:133)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.activities.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:75)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     ... 11 more
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.fragments.MyFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
01-03 13:36:19.252: E/AndroidRuntime(6144):     ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 7):

instead of this...

```
       <android.support.v4.app.Fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_myfragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.fragments.MyFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_myfragment" />
```

write like

```
       <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_myfragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.fragments.MyFragment" />
```

You can not directly reference class name in xml for `Fragment` as it does not extend `View`

Comment: Still get the same error after making these changes. I have updated my question so it is more suitable.

Comment: Gopal Rao I have added the fragment class :).

Comment: yup that is my oncreatview method there :O)

Comment: @jimbob see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143135/android-class-is-not-a-view-android-support-v4-fragment

Comment: try changing class="com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.fragments.MyFragment" to `android:name="com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.fragments.MyFragment"`

Comment: it did not make any difference :S.                 <fragment
                    android:name="tv.superawesome.club.android.ui.fragments.InviteFriendsProgressFragment"
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_invitefriendsprogress"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                     />

Comment: I think there is some Exception other than this... see your full log cat (such as NullPointerException). if possible post your full log cat too...

Comment: yes... execption is very clear... in xml you can add only fragments which are extending either android.app.Fragment or android.support.v4.app.Fragment class. but here your MyFragment is extending SherlockFragment...

Comment: if I switch it to Fragment instead of SherlockFragment it gives me a very similar error... I added it to my question...

Answer (score 3):

Change to

```
 <fragment
 android:id="@+id/fragment_myfragment"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.myapp.jimbob.android.ui.fragments.MyFragment"
  />
```

Your `MyFragment` can extend `Fragment` and you can use `SupportLibrary`. Make sure you have the proper imports and make sure your Activity extends `FragmentActivity` if you want to use fragments below api level 11 and below.

More info read

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

and

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: @jimbob can you post your full xml layout code ie the updated one

Comment: @jimbob can you show your Fragment class and the package where it is?

Comment: I have updated the question with my code. I have modified class names etc for readability.

Comment: @NitinMisra i asked the `MyFragment.java` code and comsider redesigning your layout